# Initializing AudioClassDescription struct confusion

Tags: objective-c, swift, struct, initialization

In some old `Objective-C` code that I'm porting to `Swift`, there is a line that reads:

```
AudioClassDescription descriptions[count];
```

Where `count` is a variable set a few lines above.

My question is what exactly does that do? My best guess is that it sets up an array of `AudioClassDescription`'s, but I'm not entirely sure.

A few lines below, I see that there's a `for` loop that checks `descriptions[i]` for some value.

If someone can please confirm my suspicion or provide an answer and resources, it would be extremely helpful.

**EDIT**
After some experimentation, in a command line environment, I see:
[image]
Which partially confirms my suspicion. Is it semantically equivalent to take the line mentioned above and use an `[AudioClassDescription]` in `Swift`, which is then passed to `AudioFormatGetProperty(...)`?

Comment: Your question is an overly complex way of asking "how is an array declared in C?".

Comment: HAHAHAHAH REALLY I DIDN'T EVEN REALIZE THAT. I've been out of the Obj-C stuff for so long